# How to change the contents of an activity on change of tabs which are created dynamically?

Tags: android, json, android-tabs

My tabs are created dynamically this way:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
```

`JSONObject jobj1 = new JSONObject(jsonObjectReceived);`

```
    JSONArray shifts = jobj1.optJSONArray("resultObject");
    for (int m = 0; m < shifts.length(); m++) {
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Shift " + (m + 1))
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
```

I call the method `json_parser()` after creating the tabs which parses the `json` object *jsonObjectReceived* and displays the content in a `ListView`.

```
private void json_parser(String jsonObjectReceived) {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonObjectReceived);
        JSONArray arrayOfShifts = jsonRootObject
                .getJSONArray("resultObject");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfShifts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject presentShift = arrayOfShifts.getJSONObject(i);
            String timing = presentShift.getString("shiftTimeFrom");
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ShiftTiming);
            tv.setText(timing);
            JSONArray arrayOfPatientsInPresentShift = presentShift
                    .getJSONArray("patientlist");
            if (arrayOfPatientsInPresentShift == null
                    || arrayOfPatientsInPresentShift.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO Patient",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfPatientsInPresentShift.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject presentPatient = arrayOfPatientsInPresentShift
                        .getJSONObject(j);
                String Name = presentPatient.getString("patientName");
                String SL = presentPatient.getString("bookingSequence");
                String Status = presentPatient.getString("statusFlag");

                result.add(SL + " " + Name + "\n " + Status);
                Log.i("MSG", result.toString());
            }

        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                result);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Problem is, the `ListView` is displaying all the items in the same tab.I know its because of the outer *for* loop. I want to display data from each outer "for" loop iteration in separate tabs. How do I do that?

My JSON data:[The *resultObject* array contains multiple objects, and each object contains an array *patientlist*.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5jRZ.png)
[*patientlist* contains multiple patients' details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PKtX.png)

After trying out the solution Anshul Jain suggested in the answer,
onTabSelected() looks like this:

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // show the given tab

            currentTabIndex = tabHost.getCurrentTab();

            json_parser(jsonString1, currentTabIndex);

        }
```

`json_parser()`method looks like this:

```
private void json_parser(String jsonObjectReceived, int i) {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonObjectReceived);
        JSONArray arrayOfShifts = jsonRootObject
                .getJSONArray("resultObject");
        // for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfShifts.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject presentShift =arrayOfShifts.getJSONObject(i);
        String timing = presentShift.getString("shiftTimeFrom");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ShiftTiming);
        tv.setText(timing);
        JSONArray arrayOfPatientsInPresentShift = presentShift
                .getJSONArray("patientlist");

        for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfPatientsInPresentShift.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject presentPatient = arrayOfPatientsInPresentShift
                    .getJSONObject(j);
            String Name = presentPatient.getString("patientName");
            String SL = presentPatient.getString("bookingSequence");
            String Status = presentPatient.getString("statusFlag");

            result.add(SL + " " + Name + "\n " + Status);
            Log.i("MSG", result.toString());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                result);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But app crashing.

Comment: From the Json you have given.. I think this is the flow you want.. 1) first you have list of doctors.. 2) on click of list item -> you need to display patient list in an view pager.. and.. on swipe you need to change the Actionbar title (which is a patient name).. and view pager will contain patient details.. Is this the flow you are trying to do??

Comment: Each tab depicts an individual "shift".
In each tab, I want to show patient list in that shift.And when I change the tab, I want to show the patient list for that tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity should implement `ActionBar.TabListener` which has the following methods. From `onTabSelected()` method, call the `jsonParser()` method with the proper json.

```
  @Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    //Gets called when  a tab is selected


}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}
```

Comment: Did that already.
got the index of the selected tab by using a TabHost object and the `getCurrentTab()` method and called the `json_parser()` method as follows:
`json_parser(jsonString1, tabHost.getCurrentTab());`

But app still crashing.

Comment: @NishantSharad : hey..if you can post more code about your activity, then may be I can't help. Right now looking at the current code isn't helping.

Comment: @NishantSharad: jsonObjectReceived which you mentioned in the question. Does it have information only about 1 tab or all the tabs ?

Comment: `jsonObjectReceived` is the root json object which contains objects like *responseStatus* and array *resultObject*. Meaning it contains all the data which should be parsed and only selected data from it has to be displayed. 
As shown in the pic.
And about posting some more code, i would but it shows I'm exceeding by too many characters when I post. I am a newbie here :P

Comment: see when you click on a tab , onTabSelected will be called and you will have information about tab like the index of the tab, whether the index was 0,1 or 2. Store that index in a global variable named currentTabIndex. Now instead of running for loop over arrayShifts, you can simply get the requuired array using arrayShifts.get(currentTabIndex)

Comment: @NishantSharad: did you try with this approach ?

Comment: Yes I did Anshul, but still crashing :(

Comment: @NishantSharad: earlier you were telling listview contains all the content. You didn't mention crash in the question. Seems without activity code I won't be able to help any further.

Comment: Edited the question. It has become irritatingly long may be. :P

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disturb you guys, got the solution.
Turns out I was using the wrong method all this time to get the index of the current tab. I was using `getCurrentTab()` and a `TabHost` object to call it.
Should have used `getPosition()` instead.

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // show the given tab

            try {
                json_parser(jsonString1, tab.getPosition());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
```